# How to check if a java project has only interfaces and enum

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build a core module to be used across services, its collection of enum and interfaces with(without) default implementation only. Wanted to know if its possible to impose this rule either as part of mvn build or ci flow to check if someone has pushed a class in it. Being able to done at mvn would be preferred though.

Is this even possible? If yes can someone point me how?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which is the best way but I would suggest a custom rule on sonar/findbugs/checkstyle/pmd with the appropriate plugin.

Or a custom annotation processor that you use at compile time.